# illegal offset type in isset or empty Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I get this error 
`ErrorException in Arr.php line 232: Illegal offset type in isset or empty (View: C:\firstapp\resources\views\about\contact.blade.php)` when I visit the /contact page and the contact page is

```
@extends('layouts.master')
<h1>Contact Form</h1>

@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li>
        {{$error}}
    </li>
@endforeach

{!! Form::open(['route'=>'contact_store','class'=>'form-control']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name','Name :') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email','Your E-mail Address') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('message','Your Message') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('message', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::input('Contact Me',['class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

What am I doing wrong here? The main problem is that laravel is not even telling me the line number where the issue is.
Here is the aboutController code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AboutController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('about.contact');
    }

    public function store()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The only place where you use any kind of variable is the foreach loop at the top. Shouldn't it be wrapped in an if($errors) statement?

Comment: nope that is not necessary, I have used it in other form too but it is not the problem.

Comment: Ok, haven't seen the code that passes that variable to the view :)

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Laravel automatically passes the variable `$errors` to all views. It's used by the validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last `Form::input` might be the problem, It's n ot correctly formatted for an input or if you;re after a submit button I think you need:

```
Form::submit('Contact Me',['class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control'])
```

Also install whoops if you havent already done so: use this article to help. https://mattstauffer.co/blog/bringing-whoops-back-to-laravel-5

Whoops will help indicate the error in the view/

Comment: your answer made me to identify the problem, The Problem was the last line should be `Form::submit('Contact Me',['class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control'])` not
`Form::input('Contact Me',['class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control'])`